# Adding watermark using NPOI corrupts word document

Tags: c#, apache-poi, npoi

I'm trying to use NPOI to add watermark to .docx document.

Unfortunately documentation for NPOI is very scarce.

I found one method CreateWatermark() that is suppose to add the watermark.

```
    public FileResult Test()
    {
        Stream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\wordFiles\test.docx", FileMode.Open);

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(stream);

        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy hfPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document);
        hfPolicy.CreateWatermark("My Watermark");


        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        document.Write(output);

        return File(output.ToArray(),   
        "application/msword",
        "test.docx");   

    }
```

But this corrupts the docx document. It says when trying to open it : ,,unidentified error. Localization word/header1.xml"

Have you encountered this type of problem?

Comment: Can I assume that the mention of *XLS* and *Excel* in the comments are simple typos?

Comment: @MartinLiversage yes sory :) that code was copied from somewhere else and i didnt edit the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug of NPOI. https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/issues/678 is created

Comment: The bug is fixed in NPOI 2.5.5. A new example of creating watermark in word is created. You can read the code at https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi-examples/tree/main/xwpf/CreateWatermark